# localhost - I have to type the whole direction of my projects

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, project

I use localhost:8000 (I had to set it that way because just "localhost" won't work and I don't know why), and I get into the my localhost, and then try to open one of my projects, but when I click on any of them the url bar only shows "/mypage" and shows me a blank page, so I type "localhost:8000/mypage" and it works, but why do I have to do it? I've seen other users that don't have to, they just click on a project from their localhost page and done, how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe you have a redirection in there? Can you confirm this using your debug console >> traffic

Comment: your web server is configured on port 8000. if you omit port part your browser uses port 80 only. try to configure your web server on port 80.

Comment: As this is off topic for Stack Overflow and more on topic on Server Fault - configure your webserver to use Port 80 and 443 (SSL). Use google, use the force.

Comment: Also have a look at setting up Virtual Hosts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the following file.

> C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf

and find the line

> Listen 8000 or Listen

comment this line and write new code

```
#Listen 8000
Listen 80
```